# Disable the bell in xterm (X11/XQuartz) on OS X

Tags: macos, xorg, xterm

I can't seem to figure out how to disable the bell when starting an `xterm` in XQuartz (X11) on OS X.  Once my xterm window is up I can use `xset -b` but I don't know how to do this by default.

As far as I can tell there is no startup option for the `xterm` command to achieve this (other than visual bell, which I also don't want).  I have tried putting the xset command into my `.bashrc` or into `.xinitrc` both of which cause XQuartz to fail to open an `xterm` window.

Answer (score 0):

In the newest Xquartz, you may write in a Terminal:

```
defaults write org.xquartz.X11 app_to_run /usr/bin/true
```

Then no more annoying xterm. See http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki/X11-UsersFAQ .

Comment: Unfortunately this does not answer the question at all.  I am trying to disable the bell in xterm, not disable opening an xterm window when opening x11.app.

Comment: Oooops! sorry! Was doing two things at the same time. Anyway, you can write a script in favorite bin, say, no_bell_term, with the lines: xset -b\n/usr/X11/bin/xterm; make it executable and replace the '/usr/bin/true' by this in the previous snippet. It worked for me.